# Getting the ArrayOfObjects value in MongoDb with java driver

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I need to compare the requestParam system and Email Systems system ,if both are equal ,result value should be feteched based that system

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0890e870e631865877e"), 
    "user" : "testuser", 
    "Email" : "testuser@sample.com", 
    "Batch Systems" : [
        "STAR", 
        "STORY", 
        "ITEMS",    
    ], 
    "Email Systems" : [
        {
            "Bob" : {
                "System" : "Bob", 
                **"result"** : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "Wild" : {
                "System" : "Wild", 
                "result" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "CRaft" : {
                "System" : "Craft", 
                "result" : false
            }
        }
    ]
}



public Object getDetails(@RequestParam(value = "system") String userId,
  MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(this.database);
  MongoCollection<Document> users = database.getCollection(users);
  String searchString = new String(sourceSystem);
  Document matchDoc = new Document("$Email Systems.Bob.System",searchString);
  Document projectDoc = new Document("$Email Systems","EmailSystem");
  AggregateIterable<Document> aggregateIterable = users.aggregate(Arrays.asList( new Document("$match", matchDoc)));
  Iterator iterator = aggregateIterable.iterator();
  ArrayList<Document> documents = new ArrayList();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  boolean doc  = documents.add((Document) iterator.next());
```

About Code is giving results **[Document{{Bob=Document{{System=Bob, result=true}}}}, Document{{Wild=Document{{System=Wild, result=true}}}}]**

I am not able to get the Bob result value and it should be compared with the request param system .Can anyone help me the way to get the Bob result value based on above output

Comment: There is no Kinder in your data. Isnt?

Comment: Yes . Thanks .I have updated

Comment: As its an array, you canot do that. You need to add unwind stage at the beginning of your stages

Comment: Thanks for swift response .I have already tried with unwind stage but it is empty results . AggregateIterable<Document> output = users.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                new Document("$unwind", "$Email  Systems"),
                new Document("$match", new Document("Email  Systems.Bob.result", true)
               )
        ));